# Editing an HTML Table Row and Update to Database

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql-update

I have an edit button that can be clicked in each row of the my HTML table that I currently have.

Currently, when I click "Edit", I can edit the cells in the corresponding rows and columns, but when I click the button again, which is then a save button, it will not read the value entered. I get no errors that I can see, however in my JavaScript I do a `console.log(type)` and the output is `delete` which has me very confused. It should be whatever the `case` value is in my switch statement, so in this case it should be `group_id` and `sku_group`. I then do another `console.log(dict)` and the output in the log is `Object {}` so it doesn't look like the row values are being logged. I also am getting a successful row updated message in the logs too so I would definitely think that it is just a matter of being able to get the values in the row to be read.

So my question is how can I get it to read the values and successfully update the info in the database.

HTML/PHP Table:

```
<table id="skuTable" cellspacing="5" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
    <thead>
        <tr class="ui-widget-header">
            <th class="skuRow">SKU Group</th>
            <th class="skuRow">Group ID</th>
            <th class="skuRow">Edit</th>
            <th class="skuRow">Delete</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <?php foreach ($dbh->query($sql_table) as $rows) { ?>

        <tr>
            <td class="sku_group" id="sku_group-<?=intval ($rows['SKU Group'])?>"><?php echo $rows['SKU Group']?></td>
            <td class="group_id" align="center" id="group_id-<?=intval ($rows['Group_ID'])?>"><?php echo $rows['Group_ID']?></td>
            <td><input type="button" class="edit" name="edit" value="Edit"></td>
            <td><input type="button" class="delete" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"></td>
        </tr>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript for Edit function:

```
// ----- Edit Row -----

$(document).on("click", "#skuTable .edit", function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  var tds = $this.closest('tr').find('td').filter(function () {
    return $(this).find('.edit').length === 0;
  });
  if ($this.val() === 'Edit') {
    $this.val('Save');
   if($this.id !== '.sku_group') {
        tds.prop('contenteditable', true);
   }
  } else {
    var isValid = true;
    var errors = '';
    $('#myDialogBox').empty();
    var elements = tds;
    if (tds.find('input').length > 0) {
      elements = tds.find('input');
    }
    var dict = {}; 
    elements.each(function (index, element) {
      var type = $(this).attr('class');
      var value = (element.tagName == 'INPUT') ? $(this).val() : $(this).text();
      console.log(type);
      // ----- Switch statement that provides validation for each table cell -----
      switch (type) {
        case "group_id":
              dict["Group_ID"] = value;
          break;
        case "sku_group":
              dict["SKU Group"] = value;
          break;
      }
    })
    if (isValid) {
        console.log(dict);
      $this.val('Edit');
      tds.prop('contenteditable', false);
      var request = $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "update.php",
          data: dict
        });

        request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
          if(JSON.parse(response) == true){
            console.log("row updated");
          } else {
            console.log("row failed to updated");
            console.log(response);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(jqXHR);
          }
        });

        // Callback handler that will be called on failure
        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            // Log the error to the console
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(jqXHR);
            console.error(
                "The following error occurred: "+
                textStatus, errorThrown
            );
        });

        // Callback handler that will be called regardless
        // if the request failed or succeeded
        request.always(function () {

        });
    } else {
      alert(errors);
    }
  }
});
```

Update.php script:

```
<?php

  $SKU = $_POST['SKU Group'];
  $Group_ID = $_POST['Group_ID'];

  $host="xxxxxxxxxx"; 
  $dbName="xxxxx"; 
  $dbUser="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; 
  $dbPass="xxxxxxxxxxxx";

  $pdo = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=".$host.";Database=".$dbName, $dbUser, $dbPass);

  $sql = "UPDATE SKU_Group_Dim SET [SKU Group] = '$SKU' WHERE Group_ID = '$Group_ID'";

  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  //$stmt->bindValue('[:SKU Group]', $SKU);
  //$stmt->bindValue(':Group_ID', $Group_ID)  
  $result = $stmt->execute();
  echo json_encode($result);
  if(!$result) {
      echo json_encode(sqlsrv_errors());
  }

?>
```

Comment: just a comment: you can abreviate your code using <?=intval ($rows['SKU Group'])?> instead of <?php echo intval ($rows['SKU Group'])?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you put:
`<input type="button" class="delete" ...`
then you put:
`elements = tds.find('input');`
then you looped through 'elements' and put:
`var type = $(this).attr('class');`

This explains why your switch cases have `delete` in them.

Comment: Okay....I just tested it and I got rid of my delete button entirely in my table and it logs the correct values.....however I need the delete button so how can I have both the delete button there and the values being logged correctly?

Comment: You just have to change the tag of the delete button to: `<button>` or `<div>` instead of `<input>`so it wouldn't be inside `elements`

Comment: Okay I got that, however, whenever I edit a row and save it now, it completely deletes the SKU Group value...why is that?

Comment: What do you mean by "deletes the SKU Group value"? does it become blank?

Comment: Yes it becomes blank...the value that was previously in the SKU Group row gets deleted and is no longer there

Comment: Yes and I dont see anything....i checked the network tab in the console and both columns are logging the correct values once I hit save

Comment: Just to mention: if you're not using `input` tag you have to use `$this.text()` instead of `$this.val()` to change button text

Comment: I tried your code in this pen and it works fine. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qRvoep?editors=1000

Comment: It shows that everything is working in the console, but for whatever reason the update query must be doing something to where it just deletes the SKU Group value

Comment: I did and that is what i get in my program too....however there is no database in codepen in order to see that once the update runs, it deletes the SKU Group value, like it does in mine

Comment: OH! you mean it deletes it from database .. not in html?
if so try renaming `dict["SKU Group"]` to `dict["SKU_Group"]`

Comment: Yes, it deletes from the database.  The column name in the table is SKU Group and not SKU_Group so I dont think that would work

Comment: Can you check in your php if you're receiving the "SKU Group" value?

Comment: Under my network tab in my console under Form Data, I can see that both columns have the correct values so it seems to me like i am receiving them fine

Comment: yes you're sending the values correctly, but i want you to check if you received the values correctly. you can add `echo $_POST['SKU Group'];` and see what happens

Comment: Okay, I tried that and I dont see anything being echoed

Comment: Not sure this would matter or not, but whenever i get the `console.log(type)` it gives me sku_group and group_id in the console but also gives me undefined too...again not sure that would matter though

Comment: what about `Group_ID`? can you echo it ?

Comment: I saw that but it doesn't matter, the undefined value isn't added to `dict`

Comment: If i use Group_ID then I get an unexpected token in JSON error....but no error with SKU_Group

Comment: As i said earlier **try** using `SKU_Group` instead of `SKU Group` except in the SQL query

Comment: Hey, you were right! I shouldve listened in the first place! Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: So why could there not be a space there?

Comment: You're welcome, I don't know why exactly, but i suppose the conflict happens when converting JSON to fromData

Comment: Gotcha, well thanks for the help! Greatly appreciated!

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I completely follow but I think this is what's happening:

Given this set of HTML above

```
<td class="sku_group" id="sku_group-<?php echo intval ($rows['SKU Group'])?>"><?php echo $rows['SKU Group']?></td>
<td class="group_id" align="center" id="group_id-<?php echo intval ($rows['Group_ID'])?>"><?php echo $rows['Group_ID']?></td>
<td><input type="button" class="edit" name="edit" value="Edit"></td>
<td><input type="button" class="delete" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"></td>
```

Your selector then gets all the td's that aren't `.edit`

```
var tds = $this.closest('tr').find('td').filter(function () {
  return $(this).find('.edit').length === 0;
});
```

which should return these td's

```
<td class="sku_group" id="sku_group-<?php echo intval ($rows['SKU Group'])?>"><?php echo $rows['SKU Group']?></td>
<td class="group_id" align="center" id="group_id-<?php echo intval ($rows['Group_ID'])?>"><?php echo $rows['Group_ID']?></td>
<td><input type="button" class="delete" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"></td>
```

Then this part here

```
var elements = tds;
```

Correctly makes elements have all the above td's

But then here:

```
if (tds.find('input').length > 0) {
  elements = tds.find('input');
}
```

Finds an input in one of those and sets elements to the input field

```
<input type="button" class="delete" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)">
```

So by the time you're in the each I think you're only have one element to loop through, the input itself.

try a `console.log(elements)` just before going to the each() to see exactly what you're looping through.

... after formatting all this I see you've already got your answer :P oh well